# Possible to print more than 100 rows of a data.table?

Tags: r, printing, data.table, output-formatting

The data.table has a nice feature that suppresses output to the head and tail of the table.

Is it possible to view / print more than 100 rows at once?

```
library(data.table)
## Convert the ubiquitous "iris" data to a data.table
dtIris = as.data.table(iris)
## Printing 100 rows is possible
dtIris[1:100, ]
## Printing 101 rows is truncated
dtIris[1:101, ]
```

I often have data.table results that are somewhat large (e.g. 200 rows) that I just want to view.

Comment: Since I can never find this anywhere else: the option to control column width (nchar / number of characters) is `options(datatable.prettyprint.char=5L)`.  This is only documented in the (NEWS)[https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/742ca4e2aad8b5672c447f91e0b6d9f21087b710/NEWS.md]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The print method of `data.table` has an argument `nrows`:

```
args(data.table:::print.data.table)
function (x, nrows = 100L, digits = NULL, ...)
```

You can use this to control how many rows get printed:

```
print(dtIris, nrow=105)
.....
99:          5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
100:          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
101:          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
102:          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
103:          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
104:          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica
105:          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
```

Comment: +1 Which is also FAQ 2.11. Note also that, oddly, typing `print(DT)` at the prompt (with or without `nrows`) is faster than typing just `DT`. It seems to be down to R copying the whole object in the second (more common) case (during dispatch?) before the data.table method comes along to print the head and tail. If anyone knows why R does that I'd love to know. See comments in [FR#1001 REPL print copy](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1001&group_id=240&atid=978) about `applyClosure`.

Comment: `nrows` does not work in my case, it displays the truncated table only. However, `topn` works. It's weird. I used e.g. `data.table:::print.data.table(dtIris,nrows = 100)`

Comment: In my case `n` works, but neither `nrows` nor `topn` works (R 3.3.2)

Comment: `print(DT, topn=150)` works for me to display the first 150 rows. R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) data.table_1.10.4-3
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 19):

`View()` (as in `View(iris)` or `View(dtIris[1:120,])`) doesn't truncate `data.table`s, and can often be nicer than printing/spewing out a `data.*` to the console.

Comment: Very nice!  Even works in the RStudio server environment, and lets me copy a little report into Excel for posterity.

Comment: @geneorama -- Thanks for adding that note. I usually work from vanilla Windows R gui or a Windows emacs installation and wondered how broadly `View()` is implemented. Am especially curious what it produces on a *NIX machine.

Comment: It works in linux, too, here... but I don't see how to copy a report.

Answer (score 15):

To print the top 60 and bottom 60 lines (default is top 5 and bottom 5):

```
print(dtIris, topn = 60)
```

Comment: Excellent point.  You can also set this in options, with `options(datatable.print.topn=60)`.  Also, I've learned of a feature that allows you to expand or limit the width of the printed column   `options(datatable.prettyprint.char=80L)`.  This prettyprint option is not set by default, so you have to know the command in order to use it (whereas you can search options() for other options like  `datatable.print.topn` and `datatable.print.nrows`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a data.frame only for printing:

```
iris_dt = as.data.table(iris)
print(as.data.frame(iris_dt))
```

Comment: Good workaround, but it doesn't answer the question.  If you start looking at workarounds then you could suggest a lot of things, like "just use SAS!" or "print each row one at a time!"... you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

A messy option, but you could always export it into excel to view it with excels convenience.

```
library(xlsReadWrite)
write.xls(mydata, "c:/mydata.xls")
```

Comment: data.tables are used for huge amounts of data. Have fun with Excel.

Comment: hence I put "a messy option". Depends on the size of your data.

Comment: There is messy and then there is O_O

Comment: If you are already working with R and your solution to a specific problem is to export the data to Excel, please ask on Stack Overflow for a better way.

Comment: I have to say, this is probably the most effective answer.  However, it's not a "right" answer in terms of data.table and R.  The only reason that I'm not exporting to Excel in this case is that I'm working on a server.  It's almost exactly what I do for these summaries that are in the 200-500 row range.

Comment: @Roland To be fair, I was asking about printing small data.tables to the console, which is also a size that Excel can handle.

Comment: Timothy, you may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164897/quickly-view-an-r-data-frame-vector-or-data-table-in-excel/12164899#12164899

Comment: @geneorama Why do you use `data.table` if your data size is so small? `data.table` is optimized for large data sets. For small data sets you should just use base R, i.e., a `data.frame`.

Comment: @Roland The results from a data table query are also a data table, and query results are not that large.  However sometimes they're just large enough that the full result will not print to my screen.

Comment: Over the years I've found that at some point in nearly every project I end up exporting a lot of data to Excel to debug, and I find things that I would have otherwise missed.