# Quickly view an R data.frame, vector, or data.table in Excel

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

How do you quickly open small R table / vector objects in Excel?

For example suppose you have the following three objects that you want to view in Excel:

```
## A data frame with commas and quotes
df = data.frame(
  area = unname(state.x77[,'Area']),
  frost = unname(state.x77[,'Frost']),
  comments = "Ok for a visit, but don't want to live there",
  challengeComments = c('"', '""'))
row.names(df) = state.name
df = df[1:10, ]
df['California', 'comments'] = "Would like to live here"

## A Matrix
mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 10)

## A Vector
v = 1:10
```

Comment: I wrote the question and the answer as a reference.  I'm not sure if answering my own question makes me egocentric or selfless.

Comment: If you just want to view the data in a spreadsheet like form instead of opening excel you could use `fix`, `edit`, or `data.entry`

Comment: Good call.  I thought there was something like `View` but tried view and didn't think about capitalizing it.

Comment: @Dason : use  `??view`  and `utils::View` will show up.

Comment: @geneorama - egocentric or selfless, it's actually promoted on stackoverflow! See [this blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for more details. Nice work, looks like a useful function!

Answer (score 14):

I wrote this function to accomplish that task.  I call it "write temp file", or "wtf".  It only works on windows if you have csv files associated with Excel.

You might look at the code in PBSmodelling::openFile to see how to adopt it to different operating systems.

```
wtf = function (x) {
  tempFilePath = paste(tempfile(), ".csv")
  tempPath = dirname(tempFilePath)
  preferredFile = paste(deparse(substitute(x)), ".csv", sep = "")
  preferredFilePath = file.path(tempPath, preferredFile)

  if(length(dim(x))>2){
    stop('Too many dimensions')
  }
  if(is.null(dim(x))){
    x = as.data.frame(x)
  }
  if (is.null(rownames(x))) {
    tmp = 1:nrow(x)
  }else {
    tmp = rownames(x)
  }
  rownames(x) = NULL
  x = data.frame(RowLabels = tmp, x)
  WriteAttempt = try(
    write.table(x, file=preferredFilePath, quote=TRUE, sep=",", na="",
                row.names=FALSE, qmethod="double"),
    silent = TRUE)
  if ("try-error" %in% class(WriteAttempt)) {
    write.table(x, file=tempFilePath, , quote=TRUE, sep=",", na="",
                row.names=FALSE, qmethod="double")
    shell.exec(tempFilePath)
  } else {
    shell.exec(preferredFilePath)
  }
}


wtf(df)
wtf(mat)
wtf(v)
```

if you open the same object multiple times, it will still work thanks to the error handling, but it will have a messy temp name.

```
wtf(df)
df$MoreData = pi
wtf(df)
```

Comment: Have you tested this on OSes other than Windows?  Also: depending on which WindowsOS and which version of Excel, this may start up multiple instances of the Excel app, rather than opening the .csv files in multiple windows of one instance of Excel.  That's not your fault (it's Redmond's), but I bet there's some sleek system calls that can get around those problems.

Comment: "openFile" from PBSmodelling has some clever ways to test for which OS you're using.  I figured that the desire for an R-Excel link is mostly something that windows users want.

Comment: @lselzer Thanks. The original name was "writeTemp", but I shortened it to "wt" when I started using it hundreds of times per day.  The new and improved version needed a new name... "wtf" was only natural.

Comment: So what happens if `wtf.R` gets submitted to thedailywtf.com ?

Comment: `wtf` is now on github: [geneorama/wtf.R](https://github.com/geneorama/geneorama/blob/master/R/wtf.R)

Comment: This function's name is self descriptive for when you really need an answer to WTF is going on with your data.frame.

Comment: @CaffeineConnoisseur I've waited 1,562 days for this comment

Comment: @geneorama sometimes I feel like a joke's too obvious to make, but then I realize no one is making it so I feel obligated to make it.

Comment: @geneorama I'm a bit unsure about whether the file remains in temp after you close Excel. Sometimes I can't store the data frame on the computer for security reasons. Will it delete if the R session ends? What about adding unlink() into the function, will that work?

Comment: @A.Lester Yes, the file remains in temp, and adding unlink didn't work for me because the file's open in Excel. If you trust the "secure delete" (shift delete) in Windows, then I'd say your best bet is to use the file in Excel, then find the path with a "save as" and navigate to the temp folder and delete it there (after closing). You could also try to save the file name, then delete from R, but that's complicated and likely to fail. R-Studio is already caching a lot in those temp folders, you might want to check the temp folders out regardless.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a function to open files in Libre Office Calc or Excel. [See here for details](http://jeromyanglim.tumblr.com/post/33825729070/function-to-view-r-data-frame-in-spreadsheet).

```
view <- function(data, autofilter=TRUE) {
    # data: data frame
    # autofilter: whether to apply a filter to make sorting and filtering easier
    open_command <- switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],
                           Windows= 'open',
                           Linux  = 'xdg-open',
                           Darwin = 'open')
    require(XLConnect)
    temp_file <- paste0(tempfile(), '.xlsx')
    wb <- loadWorkbook(temp_file, create = TRUE)
    createSheet(wb, name = "temp")
    writeWorksheet(wb, data, sheet = "temp", startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
    if (autofilter) setAutoFilter(wb, 'temp', aref('A1', dim(data)))
    saveWorkbook(wb, )
    system(paste(open_command, temp_file))
}
```

Comment: I have two fixes to this very handy function, the one makes it capable of handling dplyr-datasets, and the other specifies that the XLConnect function to be used within this function should be from the XLConnect package, by using the "::"-operator. This is because I've had problems with conflicting packages. Check the comments-field in the link that Jeromy suplies, if you've had issues with this function.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted something that mimicked View() but in Excel, not in the internal view of RStudio.
Learned little bits from numerous posts above.  Eventually came to a pretty simple little bit of code that....so far... seems to do the trick for me.
Just want to quickly view it, but in Excel.  If I decide I want to save the file, I can handle that within Excel.  Otherwise it just automatically create a temp file in the default temp directory for that session of R.  It's setup to act on the .Last.value of the R session as a default, or you pipe in an object that can be coerced to a data frame

I just have it defined in my R profile so its always available.
Might make more sens to name it ViewExt for "View External" so as to not link it directly to Excel but whatever program of choice the user has set in Windows to be the default editor for a .csv file.  But thats what I use so that's what I named it

```
    ViewExcel <- function(df = .Last.value, file = tempfile(fileext = ".csv")) {
       df <- try(as.data.frame(df))
       stopifnot(is.data.frame(df))
       utils::write.csv(df, file = file)
       base::shell.exec(file)
    }

    #Examples
    mtcars
    ViewExcel()
    mtcars %>% ViewExcel()
    ViewExcel(mtcars)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for shameless advertisement... You can try my package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/excel.link/index.html
It looks like:

```
library(excel.link)
xlrc[a1]=df
```

It depends on Omegahat RDCOMClient package so it is necessary install it from source:

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
install.packages("excel.link", repos = "http://cran.at.r-project.org",type="source")
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this often to paste a table of data into Excel:

```
write.table(x, "clipboard", row.names=F, sep='\t')
```

And to copy a (sub)table from Excel into R, do this (assuming the table has a header row):

```
read.csv('clipboard', sep='\t')
```

Comment: Yes, I love this trick and tab delimiters paste right into Excel.  The problem is the memory limit, and lack of Linux support.  My package (geneorama) has clipper and clipped for pasting to and from Excel (Excel to R has virtually no memory limit btw).  https://github.com/geneorama/geneorama/blob/master/R/clipper.R https://github.com/geneorama/geneorama/blob/master/R/clipped.R

Answer (score 1):

`geneorama`'s solution is great, but using `write.table` makes it very slow. You can change that to `fwrite` from the [data.table package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).

The main reason this solution is useful (at least to me) is because `View` is *terrible* with large dataframes. I tested `geneorama`'s solution with a dataframe of 15600 obs. by 1270 variables, and it opened after 16 seconds. With the `fwrite` version it opened after 0.6 seconds!

Here's the modified function:

```
wtf = function (x) {
  tempFilePath = paste(tempfile(), ".csv")
  tempPath = dirname(tempFilePath)
  preferredFile = paste(deparse(substitute(x)), ".csv", sep = "")
  preferredFilePath = file.path(tempPath, preferredFile)

  if(length(dim(x))>2){
    stop('Too many dimensions')
  }
  if(is.null(dim(x))){
    x = as.data.frame(x)
  }
  if (is.null(rownames(x))) {
    tmp = 1:nrow(x)
  }else {
    tmp = rownames(x)
  }
  rownames(x) = NULL
  x = data.frame(RowLabels = tmp, x)
  WriteAttempt = try(
    data.table::fwrite(x, file=preferredFilePath, quote=TRUE),
    silent = TRUE)
  if ("try-error" %in% class(WriteAttempt)) {
    data.table::fwrite(x, file=tempFilePath, quote=TRUE)
    shell.exec(tempFilePath)
  } else {
    shell.exec(preferredFilePath)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's true, but @geneorama didn't have `fwrite` available when he wrote it! I should rewrite my function, and maybe I will.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `view_in_xl` function from the viewxl package. This is equivalent to using F4 keyboard shortcut in RStudio.

```
viewxl:::view_in_xl(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for windows. But probably it also works on other operating systems.

It creates temporary files in C:\Users\...\Documents\Rview and opens them with browseURL(). You can open up to 99 files in parallel. You can easily choose which dimnames should be displayed by argument "names". The function will add ' before +,-,= in col/rownames so it will be displayed properly in Excel.

I personally prefer the solution using Sys.getenv("TMP") over the use of tempfile() because tempfile() will mess up your temporary files folder after a certain period of time.

See the arguments descriptions at the top of the code for further information.

```
# This function creates a CSV file from a data.frame/matrix and opens it with the default CSV-opening-program
# of the computer.
#
# x = data.frame/matrix
# names = dimnames to be saved in the file. "col"=colnames, "rowcol"=rownames&colnames, "row"=rownames, "no"=no dimnames
# nrows = maximum number of rows    to be saved (for higher speed with large datasets)
#         if n=-1, all rows will be displayed.-> see also the help for read.table()
# ncols = maximum number of columns to be saved (for higher speed with large datasets)
# folder = directory, where the temporary file should be saved.
#          If NULL an accessible folder in C:/Users/.../Documents will be created automatically.
# quote = should quotes be written into the csv File? -> see also the help for write.table()
# na = how should NA values be displayed in the csv File? -> see also the help for write.table()
# openfolder = Should the folder with all temporary files be opened after having created the file?

view <- function(x, names=c("col","rowcol","row","no"), nrows=10000, ncols=1000, folder=NULL, quote=FALSE, na="NA", openfolder=FALSE, ...){

  names <- match.arg(names)
  if(is.null(dim(x))) {
    x <- as.matrix(x)
  }
  if(is.null(colnames(x))) colnames(x) <- paste0("V",1:ncol(x))

  if(nrows<0) nrows <- nrow(x)
  if(ncols<0) ncols <- ncol(x)
  # Shrink data.frame such that it can be saved & viewed faster.
  nrows <- min(nrow(x), nrows)
  if(nrows!=nrow(x)) x <- x[1:nrows,,drop=FALSE]
  ncols <- min(ncol(x), ncols)
  if(ncols!=ncol(x)) x <- x[,1:ncols,drop=FALSE]


  # Define paths
  # If is.null(folder), wird ein temporaerer Ordner im Windows-Dateisystem angelegt.
  if(is.null(folder)) {
    folder <- paste0(Sys.getenv("TMP"), "\\Rview")
    suppressWarnings( dir.create(folder) )
  }  

  # Wenn am Schluss des Pfades kein "/" angefuegt wurde, wird dies gemacht:
  if( !substr(folder,nchar(folder),nchar(folder))%in%c("/","\\") ) folder <- paste0(folder, "\\")
  pfad0 <- folder
  name <- "Rview_tmp"
  nr <- "01"
  csv <- ".csv"

  # Check if there are existing files in the folder
  fil <- list.files(pfad0)
  # If there are no files in the folder, use the default save path.
  if(length(fil)==0){
    pfad1 <- paste0(pfad0, name, nr, csv)
  } else {
    # Remove all files in the folder (if possible)
    fil <- paste0(pfad0, fil)
    suppressWarnings( try( file.remove( fil )  , silent=TRUE) )
    fil <- list.files(pfad0)
    # If there are no files anymore use the default save path.
    if( length(fil)==0 ) {
      pfad1 <- paste0(pfad0, name, nr, csv)
    } else {
      # If there are sill files, read out the number of the newest file (with the highest number)
      ncharfil <- nchar(fil)
      mx <- max( as.numeric( substr(fil,ncharfil-5,ncharfil-4) ) )
      # Add 1 to the number of the file
      mxpl1 <- as.character( mx+1 )
      if(nchar(mxpl1)==1) mxpl1 <- paste0("0",mxpl1)
      # Create a new path
      pfad1 <- paste0(pfad0, name, mxpl1, csv)
    }
  }

  # Rownames und colnames, die mit +, - oder = anfangen, mit ' am Anfang versehen, dass es von Excel richtig dargestellt wird
  rn1 <- rownames(x)
  cn1 <- colnames(x)
  ind <- substr(rn1,1,1)%in%c("+","-","=")
  if(any(ind)) rownames(x)[ind] <- paste0(" ",rn1[ind])
  ind <- substr(cn1,1,1)%in%c("+","-","=")
  if(any(ind)) colnames(x)[ind] <- paste0(" ",cn1[ind])

  # Write CSV file & open.
  if(names=="row") {
    # If the first cell of the file is named "ID" Microsoft Excel warns that a SYLK file is opened. Therefore it is renamed.
    if(rownames(x)[1]=="ID") rownames(x)[1] <- "lD"
    write.table(x, file=pfad1, sep = ";", col.names=FALSE, row.names=TRUE, quote=quote, na=na, ...)
  } else if (names=="col") {
    # If the first cell of the file is named "ID" Microsoft Excel warns that a SYLK file is opened. Therefore it is renamed.
    if(colnames(x)[1]=="ID") colnames(x)[1] <- "lD"
    write.table(x, file=pfad1, sep = ";", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, quote=quote, na=na, ...)
  } else if (names=="rowcol") {
    write.table(x, file=pfad1, sep = ";", col.names=NA)                    # Colnames & Rownames
  } else {
    write.table(x, file=pfad1, sep = ";", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, quote=quote, na=na, ...)
  }

  browseURL(pfad1)
  if(openfolder) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    browseURL(folder)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering the question since this is not limited to Excel, but here is a simple function (inspired by some of the other answers) which creates a temp csv file from an object and copy its path to the clipboard (with the package `clipr`).

This allows to quickly visualize the object in any application (e.g. [sc-im](https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im/tree/freeze/src), Libreoffice calc, Excel, Gnumeric, etc.) by simply typing the name of the chosen application and pasting the content of the clipboard in the command line.

```r
ext <- function(data) {
    file_name <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
    file <- write.csv(data, file_name)
    clipr::write_clip(paste(file_name))
}
```

I initially resorted to this because I was struggling to get `sc-im` to open a file from within R with `system()`, but in the end, I find it very convenient to be able to chose the application I want to use to visualize the temp file: depending on the object I want to explore, one or another application might be more suitable.

Answer (score -2):

Use `write.csv(x, "clipboard")` and paste in excel.

Comment: I loved the idea till I tried it. Unfortunately, it pastes the whole line in the first cell of each row. It does not automatically put each value in its own cell.

Comment: I had to use "text to column" for the first paste, and set the correct separator. After that, it works fine for me (Excel 2007). Subsequent paste do not need "text to column" here.

Comment: Works for me, although I use OOo Calc.