# Error importing multiple csv R: No such file or directory

Tags: r

I'm trying to read multiple csv files and store them in 1 dataframe.
What I did is:

```
 files <- list.files(path="the path/", pattern="*.csv")

 df = lapply(files, read.csv,sep = ";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

I've tried also `sapply`.

I'm getting:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection cannot open
>   file 'onefile.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you set the correct working directory with `setwd("C:/ExampleFolder/")`? Seems like R can't find the file.

Comment: No I didn't cuz if I print files I get all the csvs that I need

Comment: Do the files have the correct path? Consider including `full.names = TRUE` as argument to `list.files`. I am not sure your `lapply` is correct.

Comment: Im not clear what statement the error is on. Are your 'files' listed correctly in the first statement?

Comment: @Kristoffer Winther Balling the full.names did worked but I'm getting a list not a single dataframe that groups all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` has a fast way to `rbind` a list of data frames (which is what the `lapply` returns), so using `rbindlist`:

```
library(data.table)
files <- list.files(path="the path/", pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(files, read.csv,sep = ";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

To use `fread` from `data.table` in the `lapply`:

```
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread, sep = ";", encoding = "Latin-1"),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

To do this in base R (without using `rbindlist` or `fread` from `data.table`):

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read.csv, sep = ";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
```

Comment: Yes, fread is much faster. The encoding needs to be changed to `Latin-1` though.

Comment: I'm new to R, is it normal that the print not showing all the rows and 1 csv ?

Comment: By default `data.table` only shows the head and tails of the data if there are more than 100 rows. You can change that as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162657/possible-to-print-more-than-100-rows-of-a-data-table), or convert `dt` to a data frame using `setDF(dt)`, or use the base R method I added to the answer (will result in a standard data frame).