# complex multiple csv merging in r

Tags: r, csv, merge

We have two types of dataframes DF_1 and DF_2 each read from csv files with file names of the types

1) DF_1 csv file name of randomNumbers-text1.csv for.

2) DF_2 csv file name of randomNumbers-text2.csv for.

They are perfectly merged into a single dataframe called merged_DF by

`merged_DF = merge(DF_1, DF_2)`

*Now comes the tricky part.*

The working directory is made up of around 13000 csv files where half is of the DF_1 csv file name type and the other of the DF_2 csv file type (see point 1 & 2 above).

**Problem:** How does one perform the above described perfectly merged operation on all approx. 13000 csv files and combine the output into a single combined dataframe call it combined_merged_DF?

How does one solve this the R way

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: One example using `lapply` and `rbindlist` from `data.table` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515338/error-importing-mutiple-csv-r/43515645#43515645)

Comment: Thanks Kristoffer. I do have a solution for combining multiple csv files into a single dataframe, but not a solution for outputting a single combined_merged_csv by looping trough a merge of two types of dataframes read from multiple csv files of which there are two different kinds distinguished by their csv file names.

Comment: another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32888918/2204410

Comment: See Aurèle answer which almost solved the problem. It only needs a minor change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the files in the directory are `124-type1.csv`, `723-type1.csv`, `899-type1.csv`, `124-type2.csv`, `723-type2.csv`, `100-type2.csv`, `wrong-file.csv`. You could do:

```
csv_files <- list.files("./path/to/csvs", ".csv$")
# [1] "124-type1.csv"  "723-type1.csv"  "899-type1.csv"  "124-type2.csv" 
# [5] "723-type2.csv"  "100-type2.csv"  "wrong-file.csv"

ids_in_common <- intersect(
  sub("-type1\\.csv$", "", grep("type1", csv_files, value = TRUE)),
  sub("-type2\\.csv$", "", grep("type2", csv_files, value = TRUE))
)
# [1] "124" "723"
do.call("rbind", lapply(ids_in_common, function(id) {
  merge(
    read.table(file.path("./path/to/csvs", paste0(id, "-type1.csv"))),
    read.table(file.path("./path/to/csvs", paste0(id, "-type2.csv")))
  )
}))
```

Comment: Indeed a clever protocol Aurèle, but it needs the final touch because it shows the message 

Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 5 elements

csv type2 needs a sep=";" to be read correctly.

How does one implement this in your clever protocol?

Thanks for your great solution! :)

Comment: Simply add `, sep = ";"` in `read.table(file.path("./path/to/csvs", paste0(id, "-type2.csv")), sep = ";")` maybe? Or use `read.csv2` instead? See `help(read.table)`

Comment: read.csv2 did the job. Thanks for your great answers Aurèle - It is highly appreciated! :)